# Front-Facing will darken when recording

Tags: android, android-camera, android-mediarecorder

[image: Question GIF]

The project is [googlesamples/android-Camera2Video](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video), and I changed the following code:

```
String[] cameraIds = manager.getCameraIdList();
String cameraId = cameraIds[0];
```

to

```
 String[] cameraIds = manager.getCameraIdList();
 String cameraId = cameraIds[0];
 for (String id : cameraIds) {
     Log.e(TAG, "openCamera id:" + id);
     CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(id);
     if (characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {
         cameraId = id;
         break;
        }
     }
```

Now the camera is Front-Facing.

The Question :

1. Front-Facing will darken when recording.
2. The system Videotape cant find this issue, but Google Video sample can find (My project is to learn from sample).
3. It happens just on my company device (Phone).
4. I want to know if the problem is with the device or code?

Anybody can help me?
Thank you!

Comment: "The question just in my company device(Phone)."  - you have tried other phones? The ambient light sensor is located near the front facing camera - so you might want to make sure not to cover it.

Comment: @Sebastian Roth I did not cover it. The other phone cant find this question. Run google video sample can find this question in my phone, but runing system's videotape no this question. So i am puzzled.